# Database structure for simple waiting times project with CSV data and MySql

Tags: mysql, database, csv

Suppose I have some sample data like that shown below (with a lot more entries), and my main use case is to look up a specific aliment and provide a list of waiting times for different hospitals which offer that treatment.

Not being very experienced at all with DB design, I don't know whether in this example there is an advantage to using separate tables with links between then or if a simple import of the CSV to a single table will suffice.

If I used separate tables, I'm guessing they would be for hospital and ailment perhaps?

I would be very grateful if someone tell me the best approach for this.

```
ID,Main Department,Specific Complaint,Hospital ,Waiting time
1,Cardiology,general,Hospital 1,7
2,Cardiology,general,Hospital 2,7
3,Cardiology,general,Hospital 3,7
4,Cardiology,general,Hospital 4,21
5,Cardiology,traumatology,Hospital 1,8
6,Cardiology,traumatology,Hospital 2,7
7,Dermatology,general,Hospital 1,21
8,Dermatology,general,Hospital 2,14
9,Dermatology,general,Hospital 3,21
10,Dermatology,erysipelas,Hospital 1,7
11,Dermatology,erysipelas,Hospital 3,7
...
```

Comment: Hi. Time to read a textbook on information modeling & database design.

Comment: This is a nice problem, but if we do it for you, you will never learn.  What have you done?  Did you research database modeling?  Get started, we can help you iron out kinks if any.

Comment: @Nic3500 I have studied the basics of relational databases. I have tried drawing a schematic diagram - e.g. with boxes for hospitals, units and aliments, but then I can't work out where waiting times would go. I am also aware of the rules for data normalization but not sure how to apply to this problem. This is not a homework problem, I am an adult learner self-studying and from experience I know that seeing a good solution and contemplating why it works will be more helpful at this stage then struggling without help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One detail you must understand, SO is not a teaching site, tutorials abound for that.  It is more to address specific problems that arise when developing solutions.  That being said, I like this type of question, so here goes.

The type of solution to implement (simple CSV or complete database) depends on the volume of data, and type type of reports you require.

- CSV is quick to implement.
- Database takes more time, but will allow you to produce more complex reports than CSV, through the use of queries.
- CSV is often used as a medium to load or extract data, but as for queries it is not as powerful.
- A database can be expanded.  Ex. today you only consider the name of the hospital.  You could expand your table to include the address, phone number, ...  You could also expand your model to add insurance company links, doctors, ...

Basic modeling:

- Identify your objects.  Ex. here I would consider ailment, hospital, complaint.
- Identify relations between objects, and their type.  Ex. ailment and hospital are linked, the that link is n-n.  Meaning 1 ailment can be treated in many hospitals, and 1 hospital can treat many ailments.
- I am not certain what to do with complaint.  In your question you do not specify if all hospitals treat all (ailment - complaint) duos or not.  More on that later.

As you define your structure, make sure you apply the normal forms.  In most cases, forms 1-3 are enough.

- 1NF: atomic values and no repeating groups.  Ex. you would create table with columns hospital and ailments separated by commas.  1 line == 1 hospital <-> 1 ailment.
- 2NF: 1NF is achieved and all the non-key attributes are dependent on the primary key.  Ex. you should not create a table linking ailment and wait time.  The wait time is not dependent on the ailment, it is dependent on the combination of ailment and hospital.
- 3NF: 2NF is achieved and there are no transitive functional dependencies.  So A is dependent on B, B is dependant on C, so A is transitively dependent on C.

Some critical questions must be answered before you can model your data:

- A hospital can treat a certain ailment.  In all cases?
- Can you have: hospital 1 can tread ailment 1 when the complaint is A and B, but not C?
- Ex. all hospitals can provide primary care for cardiac patients, but cardiac surgery can only be performed as some hospitals.
- In that case, you cannot link ailment and hospital together directly.  A combination of (ailment,complaint) can.  And this will impact wait time.
- Based on reality, I will link (ailment and complaint) and link this duo to hospital.

Here is my first model, "for fun", which might need to be modified for your needs:

[image]

Wait time is in table **Hospital_Treads_Ailment_has_Complaint**.  In my model, an hospital can only estimate the wait time once they know which ailment and which complaint the patient has.

A final exercise I do to test my model is try the main queries I need.  If one query cannot be done with the model, it needs to be changed.

- Which hospital treats cardiac problems?  Ok, select hospital where ailment == cardiology, complaint == *.
- Which hospital can accept patients who have trauma.  Ok, select hospital where ailment == *, complaint == trauma.
  and so on...